# Remove double quotes from text in r

Tags: r

I want to eliminate double quotes from text in R. Is there a better way to do it?
I tried below code but it's still not removing double quotes:

```
 gsub("\"", "", a$answer)
```

Comment: Please share sample data

Comment: Are the double quotes bookending the string? Or are they within the string?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you tried is that you want the regular expression (i.e. pattern) to be `\"`, but backslashes are special to R, so you need to write it twice in R so it ends up as a single backslash in the pattern.

For example,

```
withquotes <- ' this is a double quote: " '
gsub('\\"', "gone!", withquotes)
# [1] " this is a double quote: gone! "
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this without escaping the double quotes

```
gsub('"', "gone!", withquotes)
#[1] " this is a double quote: gone! "
```

#### data

```
withquotes <- ' this is a double quote: " '
```